# java applet возвращает 404 после перехода с Apex 4 на Apex 5

Tags: java, oracle, applet, oracle-apex

Господа! Не так давно обновили наш Apex c 4-ой до 5-ой версии. И почти все проблемы устранили. Однако, интересная вещь происходит с одним из апплетов.

Привожу кусок кода:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();               
log ("ErrID: "+ con.getResponseCode());
log ("ErrMSG: "+ con.getResponseMessage());
is = con.getInputStream();
```

Собственно, url мы получаем с клиента. По факту - апплет должен скачать файл по этому адресу для дальнейшего его подписания. И всё бы ничего. Но `url.openConnection()` возвращает `404 Not Found`. При этом такое происходит только в Firefox. С IE работает нормально. Всё хорошо если использовать апплет с 4-ым apex'ом.

Так же если этот url вставить в адресную строку - то всё тоже качается нормально.

Никакой прокси нет, все разрешения для java есть. (К тому же, опять-таки с того же браузера обращаясь к apex4 - всё номрально). URL вида:

```
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:7777/pls/apex/apex_util.get_blob_file?a=200&s=6873676112045&p=170&d=152705736278182997&i=152706723539434791&p_pk1=265912&p_pk2=&p_ck=u-I8uxClG0crtUmtFVFsoYnYDAs&p_content_disposition=attachment
```

К сожалению, использование firefox'а для меня критично. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение нашлось! Пробил запрос через fiddler и выяснилось, что Apex помечает сессионный "кук" отметкой "Только Http". При таком раскладе java applet не может получить доступ к нему и запрос по моему url отправляется без "кук", следовательно - сервак нам отказывает, выбрасывая 404.

Может кому-то поможет!